# Need Help on Average Python

Tags: python, average

Find the average of the values in the field [quant] greater than or equal to (337)
this is the quant field

```
quant
100
7
109
204
28
292
105
254
441
401
410
14
15
51
96
403
75
31
109
17
```

this is the code i tried

```
import csv

total = count = 0

with open('3111111a.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)  

    for row in reader:
        total += float(row[4])
        count += 1

    if count:
        average = total / count
        print('The average of the values is {}'.format(average))
```

Comment: Shouldn't you only be averaging values greater than or equal to 337?

Comment: sorry... i'm a beginner.. i am struggling with this. yes i should but  my code is wrong... i think

Comment: sum([x for x in l if x >= 337])/len(l) where l is you quant list

Comment: @Denis: That is the wrong answer. Averaging over all numbers geq 337 means you have to divide by the number of numbers geq 337.

Comment: Your code had problems with indentation. Indentation is important in Python, so please check if my edit was correct and fix everything that needs fixing so that your code looks the same as what you run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/env python
import csv
from itertools import islice

total = count = 0

with open('3111111a.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # `isslice` will skip any header/title row.
    # Generates a list of integers from the fourth CSV value
    numbers = (int(row[4]) for row in islice(reader, 1, None))
    # Generates another list of values that are >= 337
    gt337 = [i for i in numbers if i >= 337]

# Sums all the numbers in our list then divides by the number to get the average
print (sum(gt337)/len(gt337))
```

Top marks for using `with`!

You can learn more about [islice()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) from the documentation.

Have fun with `Python` :-)

Comment: i keep getting a error " invalid syntax" between print and sum.. last line

Comment: sorry - missed a `)` at the `int(row[4])` part. Fixed now.

Comment: Instead of doing `int` twice and skipping the header manually, `numbers = (int(row[4]) for row in islice(reader, 1, None))` - then create the list from it - `gt337 = [i for i in numbers if i >= 337]` etc...

Comment: i'm still getting the same problem

Comment: @Jake you're using Python 3 where `print` is a function (not a statement), so change the last line to be `print(sum(numbers) / len(numbers))`

Comment: Thank you @JonClements - for both comments. I am updating my answer accordingly. Was just trying to debug why it wasn't working too but that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

This "CSV" file is rather simple, so it doesn't look like you need to use the CSV module.
`i.strip().isdigit()` skips the leading *quant*.

```
>>> [i for i in open("average.csv", "r")]
['quant\n', '100\n', '7\n', '109\n', '204\n', '28\n', '292\n', '105\n', '254\n', '441\n', '401\n', '410\n', '14\n', '15\n', '51\n', '96\n', '403\n', '75\n', '31\n', '109\n', '17\n']
>>> l = [int(i.strip()) for i in open("average.csv", "r")\
...         if i.strip().isdigit() and int(i) >= 337]
>>> l
[441, 401, 410, 403]
>>> sum(l) / float(len(l))
413.75
```

I'm aware that this list comprehension has now become so complex that it may not be the best solution anymore, but I'll let it stay in case anyone is interested in using something like it. It is, after all, the most compact solution and you don't have to use an extra module.

Comment: What if the characters "quant" are part of the csv?

Comment: Would fail if 'quant' was the header row. Also, by the looks of the OPs code their value is the 4th in the row (`row[4]`) and they have posted a simplified CSV example.

Comment: @ilmiacs Aye, this could be ignored by prepending a `and <condition>` behind `if int(i) >= 337`, but it is not said in what form this word ("quant") may be, or if it's always "quant".