# Need help on finding AVERAGE in python

Tags: python, average

What is the average value of the numbers in the field [quant] in the range (198) and (272) inclusive

```
quant
95
189
176
200
177
340
205
203
284
88
109
83
360
67
250
56
111
439
354
143
```

this is the code that i tried.  Above is the [quant] field from where i need to find the average.

```
word_file = open('300000a.csv','r')

firstLine = True 
for line in word_file:
    if firstLine:
        firstLine = False
        continue
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split (",")
    field = int(line[0])

TotalMetalCount +=1
if  field >198 or field <272:
  metalCounts += 1
else:
    metalCounts = 1


countT +=1
if field >198 or field <272:
        count += 1
```

Comment: [`reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Please don't suggest `reduce` when you can just use `sum`

Comment: @LevLevitsky yeah... not quite sure why it's been asked again. Anyway, it must be part of a class/assignment, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522767/need-help-on-average-python asked it much better - so would suggest to the OP to read that one...

Comment: I have read your code some times, but I don't known what is the meaning of your code and the variable.

Comment: im a beginner finding it really tricky :/

Comment: The same user has already asked this question, only with minor differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486849/finding-average-value-of-numbers-in-range-298-272

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the average of a list using [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and dividing it by the [length](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len).

```
float(sum(my_list))/len(my_list)
```

If you need to grab only a few specific items and extract the average based on those you can slice the array.

```
print(float(sum(my_list[198:272]))/len(my_list[198:272]))
```

If you have a list that contains strings, and not integers you need to convert them to a list of integers before you can use sum.

```
my_list_of_integers = [int(i) for i in my_list[198:272]
print(float(sum(my_list_of_integers))/len(my_list_of_integers]))
```

Comment: Looks like, @user2370772 need to take not all elements but only part of them. So filtering list will explanation will be good for him

Comment: Ah. Yea, that is probably true.

Comment: i tried the second code and it comes up with "error" "invalid syntax" and it showing me INT in red... what should i do

Comment: I updated the example in case you use Python3.

Comment: @eandersson, the sum will behave badly in Python2 because it (probably) does an integer division.  Safer to convert both to float individually.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala True, for sure the safest, but I tested it in Python 2.7.3.

Comment: In python 2.7.3 `2/3 == 0`.  I think if you divide two sums of ints you will be in trouble unless you use some kind of `__future__` import.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you are going to be doing much more numerics than this, you should use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).  Then there will be various ways of reading CSV files as arrays.  Those arrays have a `.mean()` method, which does what you think it does.

(But if you don't do more numerics, then @eandersson answer is more proportionate).